# help with error SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'onclick'

Tags: javascript

I have a link in the html page and it has the `id="redirect"`

and this in (script.js)

```
window.onload = initAll();

function initAll(){
    document.getElementById("redirect").onclick = clickHandler;
}
function clickHandler(){
    alert("Sure!");
    return true;
}
```

I'm getting this error message

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'onclick': object is null or undefined
```

I tried this in (IE9,IE8,chrome,Firefox 4.0.1) and still not running, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write:

```
window.onload = initAll;
```

At the point of execution the document element does not exists, because you don't call the function on load. You call the `initAll()` and assigning its return value to `window.onload` which is undefined or raising the error.